# Should I install AMD graphics drivers when system working fine on standard drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

I just bought and installed a AMD Radeon R5 220 2GB graphics card in my HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR. I did nothing at all besides physically install the card and attach my second monitor (the reason I got the card). I have my first monitor plugged into the builtin Intel integrated graphics. The instructions that came with the card said that I need to install the Radeon Graphics Driver, but that my system will assign it a standard graphics driver when I first boot up. Both monitors are working just how I want then to work, but I am wondering whether or not to install the Radeon Graphics Driver because I don't want it to break the Intel Integrated graphics driver. My real question is: Should I install the Radeon Graphics Driver and will it break my Intel Graphics? My end goal is to be able to simply use two monitors. It may be important to note that I am a programmer and not a gamer. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either allow Windows to update the video driver (it will), or use the HP Driver application to update the driver, but unless you are very sure of yourself, do not update the driver on your own. No need to do this in most cases

Comment: So you are saying not to worry about it unless it becomes important?

Comment: If, in the large, it is a critical update, the sources above (Windows or HP) will do it for you. I see Lenovo System Update marking updates as critical and HP will do the same

Comment: [If it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain't_broke,_don't_fix_it).